# Replace instance with a float from within instance method?

Tags: python, class, types, python-2.7

I'm writing a Python script to parse some data. At the moment I'm trying to make a Class which creates "placeholder" objects. I intend to repeatedly pass each "placeholder" variables, and finally *turn it into* a dict, float, list or string. For reasons that would take a while to describe, it would be a lot easier if I could replace the instance by calling a method.

Here's a simplified example

```
class Event( dict ):

    def __init__( self ):

        self.sumA = 0.0
        self.sumB = 0.0

    def augmentA( self, i ):

        self.sumA += i

    def augmentB( self, i ):

        self.sumB += i

    def seal( self ):

        if self.sumA != 0 and self.sumB != 0:
            self = [ sumA, sumB ]

        elif self.sumA != 0:
            self = float( sumA )

        elif self.sumB != 0:
            self = float( sumB )
```

And what I want to do is:

```
e = Event()
e.augmentA( 1 )
e.augmentA( 2 )
e.seal()
```

...and have 'e' turn into a float.

What I am hoping to avoid is:

```
e = Event()
e.augmentA( 1 )
e.augmentA( 2 )
e = e.getSealedValue()
```

I totally understand that **"self" in my "seal" method is just a local variable**, and won't have any effect on the instance outside scope. I'm unsure however how to achieve what I want, from within the instance, where it would be most convenient for my code. I also understand I could override all the bulit-ins ( **getItem**, **toStr** ) but that complicates my code a lot.

I'm a Python noob so I'm unsure if this is even possible. Indulge me, please :)

Comment: I apologize for the question being boring, by the way, and I completely understand the downvotes from *that* perspective. I don't understand the vote to "close" at all though! This is a generic question, but not easily answered by reading documentation - the code I used is here because it's difficult to explain without using code.

Comment: I can't speak for whoever voted to close it, but it looks like a well-written and constructive question to me so I'd just assume someone's in a bad mood and didn't bother to read the question carefully or care enough to help improve it. ;-)

Comment: Crap, now it's getting upvoted because of my complaining. Stop it! Downvotes are fine and probably warranted, just please don't close it outright

Comment: It *is* a good question, it just... doesn't have any good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under some circunstances, Python allows you to change the class of an object on the fly. However, not **any** object can be converted to **any** class, as the example below demonstrates (newlines added for readability):

```
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
...
>>> class B(object):
...   pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>

>>> a.__class__ = B
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.B'>

>>> a.__class__ = int
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types
```

(I don't know the exact rules from the top of my head, but if your classes uses `__slots__` for instance they must be compatible for the conversion to be possible)

However, as other answerers pointed out, in general it's a very bad idea to do so, even if there was a way to convert every reference to one object to a reference to another. I wouldn't go as far as saying *never* do that though, there might be legitimate uses of this technique (for instance, I see it as an easy way of implementing the [State Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) without creating unnecessary clutter).

Comment: This was helpful. I see that "class assignment" error is also described on python.or as "object layout differs" so I will try to change my "seal" method to remove any members/methods that differ from the target Class. If it works, I don't really see the downside of my program throwing errors if a second instance is created when I only intended to create one - if anything, it's stricter error checking for free, no? Also, the "state design" link is helpful - I need to read it more carefully

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot have an variable value replace itself by calling a method on it. The normal way to do this would be what you stated: `e = e.getSealedValue()`

You can make an object change behavior, but that's generally considered a bad idea and is likely to result in highly unmaintainable code.

Comment: 1. you can completely change behavior of an object by calling its method (despite it being a bad idea) 2. `e = ..` doesn't replace the object. It binds the name `e` to another object.

Answer (score 2):

Even if there was some sane way to make it work, I would avoid going down this path simply because it changes the type of the object to something completely incompatible with its existing contract.

Now, one could say "but I'm only using it in one place, other code paths won't ever see the old contract", but unfortunately that isn't an argument for this mechanism since you could simply only make the value available for the other code paths once you have the final object.

In short, don't do this and don't even try.